# solr getinstance is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, solr, solrnet

I am using solr to create indexes on documents. From my visual studio when running the web application everything is working fine. But on the production server i get an error:

```
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here is the stack trace

```
at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.get_Current() in        

  c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocator.cs:line 17
  at Fusion.Search.IndexManagerBase`1.GetSolrOperations() in C:\code\src\Fusion.Search\IndexManagerBase.cs:line 42
  at Fusion.Search.IndexManagerBase`1.AddFile(String fileName, Stream file, T doc, Boolean commit) in C:\code\src\Fusion.Search\IndexManagerBase.cs:line 97
  at Fusion.Search.IndexManagerBase`1.AddFile(String fileName, Stream file, T doc) in C:\code\src\Fusion.Search\IndexManagerBase.cs:line 92
  at Fusion.Search.Recruitment.CVStore.AddCV(String fileName, Stream cv, CVDocument doc) in C:\code\src\Fusion.Search\Recruitment\CVStore.cs:line 56
```

the code where the error happens

```
 public ISolrOperations<T> GetSolrOperations()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<T>>();
    }
```

regards

Comment: Obvious question: does `ServiceLocator.Current` implement a `GetInstance` method for type `ISolrOperations<CVDocument>`?  Or does a generic templated version of that method rely on calls to other methods that might break?

Comment: I published with the "All files in the project" option, and it seems to work now, some file was probably not published. I am not going to find out which file though, I have wasted enough time on this

Answer (score 0):

I published with the "All files in the project" option, and it seems to work now, some file was probably not published. I am not going to find out which file though, I have wasted enough time on this